# Change default .nuget/package folder .NET Core

Tags: nuget, .net-core-rc2, dotnet-cli, .net-core

Text from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-restore):

> If not specified, the default NuGet package cache is used. It is found in the **.nuget/packages** directory in the user's home directory on all operating systems (for example, /home/user1 on Linux or C:\Users\user1 on Windows).

Can I change .nuget/packages location?

My local NuGet.Config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="My Local Feed" value="C:\Users\IEUser\Documents\My Local Feed" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="Microsoft and .NET" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
</configuration>
```

What should I change?

Comment: Change the repository path in nuget.config.  Documentation for the config file is here: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file